# Azure Data Factory: event not starting pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've set up a Azure Data Factory pipeline containing a copy activity. For testing purposes both source and sink are Azure Blob Storages.

I wan't to execute the pipeline as soon as a new file is created on the source Azure Blob Storage.

I've created a trigger of type BlovEventsTrigger. Blob path begins with has been set to //

I use Cloud Storage Explorer to upload files but it doesn't trigger my pipeline. To get an idea of what is wrong, how can I check if the event is fired? Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Reiterating what others have stated:

- Must be using a V2 Storage Account
- Trigger name must only contain letters, numbers and the '-' character (this restriction will soon be removed)
- Must have registered subscription with Event Grid resource provider (this will be done for you via the UX soon)
- Trigger makes the following properties available `@triggerBody().folderPath` and `@triggerBody().fileName`. To use these in your pipeline your must map them to pipeline paramaters and use them as such: `@pipeline().parameters.paramaetername`.

Finally, based on your configuration setting blob path begins with to `//` will not match any blob event. The UX will actually show you an error message saying that that value is not valid. Please refer to the [Event Based Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger#examples-of-event-based-triggers) documentation for examples of valid configuration.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug with Blob storage trigger, if you have more than one trigger is allocated to the same blob container, none of the triggers will fire.

For some reasons (another bug, but this time in Data factories?), if you edit several times your trigger in the data factory windows, the data factory seems to loose track of the triggers it creates, and your single trigger may end up creating multiple duplicate triggers on the blob storage. This condition activates the first bug discussed above: the blob storage trigger doesn't trigger anymore.

To fix this, delete the duplicate triggers. For that, navigate to your blob storage resource in the Azure portal. Go to the Events blade. From there you'll see all the triggers that the data factories added to your blob storage. Delete the duplicates.
[image]

Comment: Just a note, that as of July 2019, if you have two triggers on the same container you will need to use a "sub-folder" structure for filtering the events from event grid. This is where you use the "Blob path begins" and "ends with" parameters.

For example:

Trigger #1 - container/foo/foo.csv
Trigger #2 - container/bar/bar.csv

These will filter properly and trigger independently. Here is an example of the parameters to match. 

![Valid Trigger](https://content.screencast.com/users/kirikintha/folders/Jing/media/62c1ba79-574a-4487-ad8d-26b3a70149e5/00000089.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please reference this. First, it needs to be a v2 storage. Second, you need register it with event grid.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/db332ac9-2753-4a14-be5f-d23d60ff2164/azure-data-factorys-event-trigger-for-pipeline-not-working-for-blob-creation-deletion-most-of-the?forum=AzureDataFactory

Comment: Yes, I'm using v2 storage and also registered event grid. Is there a way to debug, so I can verify that the event is fired or how do I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Did you also check this rule?  "Also make sure that the name of your trigger only contains alphanumeric letters, digits, and the '-' character. Whitespace or special characters are not allowed"

Comment: @FangLiu I'm facing the same issue as the OP and my Storage Event Triggers have an "_" in them. They work fine in DEV and QA environment but don't fire in UAT environment when a blob is uploaded. Each environment has it's own ADF and Storage Account V2. Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

And now, on 20.06.2021, same for me: event trigger is not working, though when editing it's definition in DF, it shows all my files in folder, that matches. But when i add new file to that folder, nothing happens!

Comment: Just wondering if you were able to fix the issue? If yes, could you please mention what was done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating your trigger via arm template, make sure you're aware of [this bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/01246c8f-b1ca-4d39-87b0-9a66742f2f89/unable-to-activate-triggers-in-data-factory-as-part-of-cicd-deployment?forum=AzureDataFactory).  The "runtimeState" (aka "Activated") property of the trigger can only be set as "Stopped" via arm template.  The trigger will need to be activated via powershell or the ADF portal.

Answer (score 0):

An event grid resource provider needs to have been registered, within the specific azure subscription.

Also if you use Synapse Studio pipelines instead of Data Factory (like me) make sure the Data Factory resource provider is also registered.

Finally, the user should have both 'owner' and 'storage blob data contributor' on the storage account.