# Azure Blob creation not firing Azure Data Factory event trigger

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I've Event trigger in Azure Data Factory, it triggers when a new blob is created in Azure Blob storage. But my trigger is not firing on Blob creation.

Followed below link but stuck at below mentioned point:
[Azure Data Factory: event not starting pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134475/azure-data-factory-event-not-starting-pipeline).

Environment details:

Event Grid is registered, ADF is v2 and passing parameters to pipeline.
My question is do I need to have Azure storage event subscription activated? If so what should be my event handler(which in my case is ADF pipeline)?

Please suggest:

1. Azure Storage Event subscription is mandatory to fire Blob creation triggers? if yes then Event Handler option.
2. If it is not mandatory(as per my research only Event Grid has to be registered) what is causing my Event trigger to not fire?

Answer (score -1):

Must be using a V2 Storage Account

Trigger name must only contain letters, numbers and the '-' character (this restriction will soon be removed)

Trigger makes the following properties available @triggerBody().folderPath and @triggerBody().fileName. To use these in your pipeline your must map them to pipeline paramaters and use them as such: @pipeline().parameters.paramaetername.

Have you followed above guidelines? If yes, maybe you could consider create a support ticket.

Comment: Yes did follow all of these, How about my question about  Azure storage event subscription creation? Is it mandatory if so which option to choose in  Event Handler ?

Comment: As far as I know, register event grid should be enough.

Comment: This answer seems to be just repeating what the OP had already read at his link.